# Antd tabe filter with number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i want to use filter with set of number values to filter table
for example look for acount with 0 or Null
[image: antdTable]

this does not work for me
`

```
filters: [
        { text: "zero", value: 0 },
        { text: "null", value: "null" }
      ],
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to insert onFilter function, example:

```
const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age",
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.age === value,
      filters: [
        {
          text: "null",
          value: null
        },
        {
          text: "0",
          value: 0
        }
      ],
      filterSearch: true,
      sortDirections: ["descend"]
    }
  ];
```

[codsandboxexample](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-vv9iur)